# Integration involving DiracDelta

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, generalized-function, distributions

I tried the following integration

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[Tan[x]], {x, -4, 4}]
```

I got `1` as the result. However, between -4 and 4 Tan[x] has 3 roots. `x0=-Pi`, `x1=0` and `x2=+Pi`

On paper, I would use the scaling and multiple zeros rules of the dirac delta function which converts the integrand into 3 integrands each of the form `DiracDelta[x-x_i]` with the scaling function `1/Abs[1+Tan[x_i]^2]` infront. Each scaling factor evaluates to 1 at each root, and the integration over the each 3 dirac deltas return 1 which sums up to `3` not 1.

Why does MMA give 1? Could anyone explain the math behind MMA's result?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109645/discussion-on-question-by-dark-lord-integration-involving-diracdelta).

Comment: It might just be a bug. That part of the integrate code might have trouble when the part inside is not a linear expression in the variable of interest. (Or maybe it handles some generalizations but not all).